# Cross Process Read after Write File Consistency

Tags: c++, c, windows

Is cross process file read after write consistency guaranteed, specifically on Windows?

i.e. is this a correct program:

```
// proccess1:

char tag = 0xF2;
char buf[256];
while (true) {
   fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
   fread(buf, sizeof(char), sizeof(buf), file);
   if (buf[0] == tag)
     break;
   sleep(1);

}
printf(&buf[1]); // Hello World
```

-

```
// process2:
char tag = 0xF2;
char[] buf = "Hello World";
sleep(rand() % 10);
fseek(file, 1, SEEK_SET);
fwrite(str, sizeof(char), sizeof(buf), file);
fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
fwrite(&tag, sizeof(char), 1, file);
```

Answer (score 0):

While reading when someone else is writing can cause problem when read and write operations are on same block of data thus can give unpredictable data.

Reading from different block and writing in another will not cause any problem.

Simultaneous read and write cannot cause your program to crash.